# Transform Family Link Functions in GLM predictions in R

Tags: r, glm

This is probably an obvious question that I just can't find, but I am looking for the different prediction transformations (in R code) for the different family/link functions for GLM.

example I know that when I run a GLM with a `family=poisson(link = "log")` function I must transform my predicted values as `exp(df$predictedvalue)`.
How do I transform `family=binomial(link = "logit")`?  I have scoured google, but can't seem to find code to do this.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The canonical way is to use the `$linkinv` component of the family. This is a function that provides the inverse of the link function for the family used.

For example:

```
> b <- binomial()
> b$linkinv
function (eta) 
.Call(C_logit_linkinv, eta)
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

which is the inverse of the logit link function as that is the default for `binomial()`.

You can extract the family from a fitted model using the `family()` function:

```
## from ?glm
clotting <- data.frame(u = c(5,10,15,20,30,40,60,80,100),
                       lot1 = c(118,58,42,35,27,25,21,19,18),
                       lot2 = c(69,35,26,21,18,16,13,12,12))
mod <- glm(lot1 ~ log(u), data = clotting, family = Gamma)
fam <- family(mod)
```

the last line of returns the following object

```
> str(fam)
List of 12
 $ family    : chr "Gamma"
 $ link      : chr "inverse"
 $ linkfun   :function (mu)  
 $ linkinv   :function (eta)  
 $ variance  :function (mu)  
 $ dev.resids:function (y, mu, wt)  
 $ aic       :function (y, n, mu, wt, dev)  
 $ mu.eta    :function (eta)  
 $ initialize:  expression({  if (any(y <= 0))  stop("non-positive values not allowed for the 'gamma' family")  n <- rep.int(1, n| __truncated__
 $ validmu   :function (mu)  
 $ valideta  :function (eta)  
 $ simulate  :function (object, nsim)  
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "family"
```

The `linkinv` component is the function containing the inverse of the link function used, here the inverse as this is the default for family `Gamma`.

If you predict from this family you can use the function to transform the values on to the response scale

```
> pred <- predict(mod, type = "link")
> fam$linkinv(pred)
        1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8 
122.85904  53.26389  40.00713  34.00264  28.06578  24.97221  21.61432  19.73182 
        9 
 18.48317
```

Of course, if you know what the inverse function is you can probably find it in base R or write your own function. The inverse of the logit link function for the binomial family mentioned earlier can also be found in function `plogis()` for example. `exp()` can be used for the `log()` link.

For more complex models that use the family mechanism, you may just find it easier to extract the relevant info from the fitted model as shown above so that you get the function right for the *implementation* you are using.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Gavin, this makes total sense!